# Gulp workflow (boostrap,scss,jquery).How to import html files to index.html?

Tags: gulp

I'm trying to do workflow with Gulp (boostrap,scss,jquery,js).

```
Structure:

  -node_modules  

    -public
     |-------assets 
     |       |  |  |
     |       |  | css---main.min.css
     |       |  js---app.js
     |     Images
     | 
    index.html

    -src
     |-------assets 
     |       |  |  |
     |       |  | css------------files
     |       |  js---app.js       |  |
     |     Images                 |  custom.scss
     |                          vendors.scss 
     | 
    index.html

   -gulpfile.js    -package.json`enter code here`    -package-lock.json
```

The idea:

```
In src/assets/css take vendors (@import "node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";) convert and minify css to public/css---main.min.css.
In src/assets/app with gulp import



( "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js","node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js","src/assets/js/**/*.js)"
```

and convert/minify in public/assets/app.

Every changes on src directory reflect to public.All work correctly.
All i want to include/import files from:

```
 src
  |
  |
includes/---html/files

to src
    |
    |
  index.html

example:
src/includes/header.html (<h1> hello </h1>)
import to my src/index.html

like --> @@include("header.html")
```

Only need text in that include file (styles and js loadded dynamicly)
Is it possible with my structure?

```
src/index.html ->

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Test</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/main.min.css">
</head>

<body>
  <button class='btn btn-success btn-block p-3 text-center w-25 mx-auto mt-2' id='btn'> CLICK </button>

 <div class='p-2 d-block element1 mr-5 m-2'>css-test1</div>
 <div class='p-2 d-inline element2 mx-5 bg-dark' >css-test2</div>
</body>

<script src="assets/js/app.js"></script>

</html>

gulpfile.js -->

const gulp = require("gulp"),
  browserSync = require("browser-sync").create(),
  sass = require("gulp-sass"),
  autoprefixer = require("gulp-autoprefixer"),
  cleanCSS = require("gulp-clean-css"),
  rename = require("gulp-rename"),
  newer = require("gulp-newer"),
  purgecss = require("gulp-purgecss"),
  concat = require("gulp-concat"),
  uglify = require("gulp-uglify"),
  size = require("gulp-size"),
  imagemin = require("gulp-imagemin");


function css() {
  return gulp
    .src("./src/assets/css/main.scss")
    .pipe(sass())
    .pipe(autoprefixer())
    .pipe(cleanCSS({ compatibility: "ie8" }))
    .pipe(
      rename(function(path) {
        path.extname = ".min.css";
      })
    )
    .pipe(
      purgecss({
        content: ["./src/**/*.html"]
      })
    )
    .pipe(gulp.dest("./public/assets/css"))
    .pipe(browserSync.stream());
};

function js() {
  return gulp
    .src([
      "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js",
      "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js",
      "src/assets/js/**/*.js"
    ])
    .pipe(concat({ path: "app.js", stat: { mode: 0666 } }))
    .pipe(uglify())
    .pipe(gulp.dest("./public/assets/js"))
    .pipe(browserSync.stream());
};

function html() {
  return gulp.src("./src/**/*.html").pipe(gulp.dest("./public"));
}



function serve() {
  browserSync.init({
    server: {
      baseDir: "./public"
    }
  });
}

const dir = {
  src: "src/",
  build: "public/"
};

const imgConfig = {
  src: dir.src + "images/**/*",
  build: dir.build + "images/",
  minOpts: {
    optimizationLevel: 5
  }
};

function images() {
  return gulp
    .src(imgConfig.src)
    .pipe(newer(imgConfig.build))
    .pipe(imagemin(imgConfig.minOpts))
    .pipe(size({ showFiles: true }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(imgConfig.build));
}


function customSync(){

  css()
  browserSync.reload();
}

gulp.watch("./src/*.html", html).on("change", customSync);
gulp.watch("./src/assets/css/**/*.scss", css);
gulp.watch("./src/assets/js/**/*.js", js);
gulp.watch("./src/images/**/*", images);

exports.default = gulp.parallel(html, css, js, images, serve);
```

link to my reppo --> https://github.com/Markov88/gulp-workflow-bootstrap-scss-js-

Comment: Please do not add 'solved' on the title. If you actually solved it by yourself and have an answer, then post it as such. You can also leave other the possibility to answer. If it was due to a typo or any other non reproductible error, then safely delete your post.

Comment: Incorporate a templating engine such as nunjucks into the build process and modularize your html.